# Disabling XtraGrid password column while editing

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a grid with a hidden password column, created by using [`RepositoryItemTextEdit.PasswordChar` property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemTextEdit_PasswordChartopic). I want to see a plain text while editing this column, and back to asterisks when leaving editor.

how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Create two text edits, and set the one with password char to the column:

```
plainTextPasswordTextEdit = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
hiddenPasswordTextEdit = new RepositoryItemTextEdit()
{
  PasswordChar = '*'
};

passwordColumn.ColumnEdit = hiddenPasswordTextEdit;
```

Register to [`GridView.CustomRowCellEditForEditing` event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEditForEditingtopic), and replace the column edit:

```
private void CustomRowCellEditForEditing(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Column == passwordColumn)
  {
    e.RepositoryItem = plainTextPasswordTextEdit;
  }
}
```

Only the edited row will reveal its password, and it will become hidden again after leaving the editor.